# Passing variables to custom block

Tags: theming, 8

I am trying to pass variables to a custom block in a module. I can see that the custom block is used in the code, however I cannot get the variables to show up.

Any help much appreciated:

I am themeing the block in the module file

```
function etypeservices_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
   return [
    'block__etypeservices' => [
      'variables' => [
        'facebook' => '',
     ],
   ],
];
}
```

I am building the render array

```
class SocialBlock extends BlockBase implements BlockPluginInterface {
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function build() {
    $config = \Drupal::config('etypeservices.settings');
    $facebook = $config->get('facebook');
    return [
      '#theme' => 'block__etypeservices',
      '#facebook' => $facebook,
   ];
 }


}
```

and here is the template

```
{%
    set classes = [
   'block',
   'block-social-icons',
   ]
%}
<div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
   <ul class="list-style-none">
    {% if facebook %}
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/{{ facebook }}" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>
    {% endif %}
   </ul>
</div>
```

Can anybody see why this is not working?

Comment: Your code must work. Maybe your config is bad? Try to replace "'#facebook' => $facebook" by "'#facebook' => "TEST""

Comment: And your template filename must replace the underscore by a dash! So it should be named block--etypeservices.html.twig

Answer (score 2):

For a custom template use your own theme hook `etypeservices`:

```
function etypeservices_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
   return [
    'etypeservices' => [
      'variables' => [
        'facebook' => '',
     ],
   ],
];
}
```

Which uses it's own variables space:

```
public function build() {
    $config = \Drupal::config('etypeservices.settings');
    $facebook = $config->get('facebook');
    return [
      '#theme' => 'etypeservices',
      '#facebook' => $facebook,
   ];
 }
}
```

**etypeservices.html.twig**

```
{{ facebook }}
```

The content of the block is a normal render array, which can contain one or more custom templates to make them accessible in theming. These custom templates are reusable, not only in blocks.

In a module you can override the block template, as you tried to do by using `block__...`, but you need this in very rare cases. In drupal core there is only one. Then you will inherit the variables of the base hook `block`.

But normally you leave the block template as it is, so that it can be themed on it's own.